# Get text after after html tag using Jsoup and create ArrayList

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get text from the HTML document into ArrayList using Jsoup. My document looks like this.

```
<p>
   <b>1</b>First Text
   <b>2</b>Second Text
   <b>3</b>Third Text
   .
   .
   .
   .
</p>
```

From the above document, I am want to create Array like below.

```
list{[First Text],[Second Text],[Third Text]}
```

Appreciate your help.

Tried with below code, but getting numbers only.

```
Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(chapter);
Element vve = doc1.body();
Elements vvv = doc1.select("p").select("b");
```

My Result is

```
vvv.get(0) = <b>1</b>
vvv.get(1) = <b>2</b>
.
.
.
```

Comment: I tried with following code. but I am getting numbers only like 1 2 3
    Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(chapter);
    Element vve = doc1.body();
    Elements vvv = doc1.select("p").select("b");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the complete code which I completed last night.

```
        Elements elements = doc.body().select("p").select("b");
        for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++){
            Element para = elements.get(i);
            versesList.add(para.nextSibling().toString());
        }
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark this topic as finnished :-)

Comment: how can i do it? to make it finished

Comment: i guess you did it alreay, because there's a green check.

Answer (score 1):

This will help

```
Elements elements = doc.body().select("p");

for(int j=0;j<elements.size();j++){
     Element para = tblelements.get(j);
     String value = para.select("b").get(i).text();
}
```

Comment: I am getting  value 1 only. If I don't print text in loop, I am getting value like this
    <b>1</b>

Comment: if you cna change your html like this 
<b>3</b><span>Third Text</span>

than you can try - para.select("span").get(i).text();

Comment: else try this

para.get(i).text();

this will return entire paragrapgh..then iterate each line, remove the <b> </b> tags and format your output as needed

Comment: have you used UTF-8 encoding?

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8", "");

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this:

```
final String html = "<p> ... "; // your HTML here

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


for( Element element : doc.select("b") )
{
    list.add(element.nextSibling().toString());
}
```

**Note:** You can use `List<Node>` as well, then you only have to remove the `toString()` call.